# pymongo extract objectID from find

Tags: python, pymongo

hello i have the following mongodb collection:

```
> db.attributes.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a4445fd901f278f8685b91"),
    "values" : [
        {
            "code" : "AQ",
            "pmsCode" : "638c",
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "Aqua"
            },
            "tcxCode" : "16-4529 TCX",
            "hexCode" : "#00aed8",
            "images" : [
                "AQ.jpg"
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a4445fd901f278f8685b17")
        },
        {
            "code" : "AQ",
            "pmsCode" : "3115c",
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "Aqua"
            },
            "tcxCode" : "",
            "hexCode" : "#00c4db",
            "images" : [
                "AQ.jpg"
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a4445fd901f278f8685b18")
        }],
    "name" : {
        "en-UK" : "Colour"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a4445fd901f278f8685bac"),
    "values" : [
        {
            "code" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a4445fd901f278f8685b92"),
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "0-3 MTHS"
            }
        },      {
            "code" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a4445fd901f278f8685b93"),
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "ONE SIZE"
            }
        }
,
    "name" : {
        "en-UK" : "Size"
    }
}
```

basically a collection that has two object `Colour` and `Size` which have sub-objects called `values`

what is the correct way to find the `ObjectId` for specific `Colour` values code using pymongo?

I have this `attribute_id = attributes.find({"values.code": product_color_code})` but how do i extract the actual ObjectID from this?

any advise much appreciated.

Comment: The find command returns a Cursor. See the documentation: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try using `select _id from table_name GROUP BY _id HAVING some_condition_on_colout` methods of SQL

in mongodb using python, you can do the following

```
ideas.aggregate([
    {"$match": {'colour':'some_Color_of_ur_choice' }},
    {'$group':{'_id': "$_id",'count':{"$sum": 1 } }}
    ])
```

this will help u even count no. of occurrences of colours according to the ObjectIds